# How to target class with a space at the end?

Tags: css

I have this HTML

```
<dt class="first_name ">First Name</dt>
```

How I can target this class with a space at the end ?

Comment: Are you trying to use this as a unique class

Comment: you can use like this : dt.first_name{
// property here
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple `.first_name` if you want it to be unquie you can do `dt.first_name`

Answer (score 1):

Just like without the space:

```css
.first_name {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<dt class="first_name ">First Name</dt>
```

Answer (score 1):

Space doesn't matter. This should work

```
.first_name{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS separates class names with spaces, you can target that class with `.first_name`.